# Non-required field validation error blocking form submission

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, formvalidation.io

Form-validation is blocking me from submitting as there is non-required field present in form with invalid data.

**Is it suppose to be like this?**

Following is the detailed scenario of my problem:

I have an `input type file` element in my form. This element can be empty and its not required. I have added some validation for type and size of the file.  Following is the HTML structure of the element.

`<input 
    type="file" 
    class="file-upload-component form-control" 
    name="letters" 
    id="letters-file-upload-component" 
    data-fv-notempty="false" 
    data-icon="false" 
    data-buttonname="btn-primary" 
    data-fv-file="true" 
    data-fv-file-extension="jpeg,jpg,png,pdf" 
    data-fv-file-type="image/jpeg,image/png,application/pdf" 
    data-fv-file-maxsize="5000000" 
    data-fv-file-maxfiles="2" 
    data-fv-file-message="Please upload a file in correct size (less than 5MB) and supported formats (pdf, jpg, png) only." 
    data-fv-field="letter" 
    tabindex="-1" 
    style="position: absolute; clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);"
>`

Now, when I try to upload a invalid file type or file with size more than the specified size, form validation is triggering and showing validation message. This is perfect!

But when I trying to submit form, its not happening as there is an invalid field (and non-required) field in the form.

Current solution is : **My current solution for this is to, reset field before submitting the form**
But I would like to do it without listening to form submit event.

Comment: anything in the console? Maybe an error prevents the click-handler to continue

Comment: @DasSaffe no error in console